# Mule UDP Inbound Endpoint's socket is blocked

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, mule, endpoint

I'll post as much as possible here and I'll add more info upon your requests in the comments

I have a mule flow that takes SNMP packets over UDP (Inbound UDP Endpoint) and then passes the message to a transformer that transforms the byte array (The packet) into an **Trap** object then if this trap of some specific kind I'll just log it and ignore it, otherwise, it will be logged and inserted into DB in addition to some updates (The figure below illustrates the my flow).

[image: The mule flow]

The application will be listening on port **17985** for coming SNMP traps from an **agent**, now if the agent have lot of traps the UDP socket's **Recv-Q** will be like in the figure below and the UDP endpoint will stop to log any events (Traps to DB nor Log messages to log file)

[image: netstat snapshot]

***What did I do?***

- I tried to increase endpoint buffer size to be 10MB.
- I tried to increase system buffer size to 25MB but no matter how much is it, it will be filled up as soon as the agent starts to get **crazy**

***Additional Info***

- The agent may sometimes send up to 400~600 traps per second.
- Trap's packet size is ~1500 bytes max.
- The database is very fast, no more optimization is needed there I think.

Comment: It's pretty hard to diagnose a problem with no code, let alone a possible performance problem.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I don't have too many lines of code :) tell me what code do you want to see exactly? it is not possible to post all the code here plus I think it is config problem but I don't know what to do with it!